What does Sakura use when her breasts feel uncomfortable at night?
In Fate/stay night's Heaven's feel route (5th day), Sakura stays over at Shirou's house. Since it wasn't planned, Sakura doesn't have any change of clothes and Taiga offers to lend her underwear to Sakura. The following conversation ensues:



Sakura whispers something to Taiga about something she does to alleviate what I assume is the pressure on her breasts at night (in Japanese they say くるしい). Taiga then answers as if that method is only available for use by young people, and that she will have the young people at her home get some item for Sakura the next day (in Japanese, うちの若いのに揃えさせておく).
Is Taiga saying that she will get some bra for Sakura? In that case what is the method that Sakura uses to alleviate the pressure on her breasts?
If that's not what Taiga is saying, then what is the item that both Taiga and Sakura are referring to and that allows to alleviate the pressure?
If this is answered later in the VN, please put your answer in spoiler formatting. Thank you!

It's never explicitly stated or brought up again, but it's implied to be a night/sleeping bra, as opposed to an underwrite bra.

Maybe I'm as dense as Shirou, but why would a sleeping bra be something that only Taiga should hear about? Also why would it only be reserved to young people?

It's a conversation among girls about underwear.

They openly discuss bras just before though. Why would a conversation about sleeping bra be any different?

Clearly Sakura is embarrassed about something, being a shy person, in front of Shirou at least. It could be a night bra it could be something else. If is not a night bra it could be a sarashi. Those cotton bandage things you see in anime/manga.
